# Generating a PDF with non-printable background

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, tcpdf, mpdf

In Adobe Acrobat there is an option to add a "background" to a PDF file and set the default settings that this image should be visible when opening the document but should not be printed out. I want to automate the process by a PHP script.

I checked all the popular PHP PDF libs (TCPDF, FPDF, mPDF, ...) but none of them seems to provide such an option. All I found is adding images by the ->Image method and place it behind the text. This does work when viewing the document, but of course it is also printed out.

A second approach is to render plain HTML and include custom stylesheets. I created the simple HTML

```
<h1>Simple text.</h1>

<div>
    <p>Should be printed.
    <img src="..."></p>
</div>

<div class="no-print">
    <p>Should NOT be printed.
    <img src="..."></p>
</div>
```

and saved the CSS in print.css

```
.no-print {
    display: none;
}
```

and included it by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media=“print” type="text/css" href="print.css">
```

The result does not show the second div. I guess the PDF libs do not evaluate the media in the link tag. To be honest this approach does not feel right, especially because PDF !== HTML.

Nevertheless I cannot imagine that this is so difficult. How do all the big companies manage this? I'm grateful for every hint!

Comment: Check [this](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=75) out.

Comment: Oliver thank you so much. The right keyword was "visibility", I honestly didn't think of that term. 
For all, who search for this, there is a possibilty in TCPDF as well: https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_024/